# Google wallet integration in android application

Tags: android, sandbox, android-pay

I am working on Google wallet integration in android application. I have read the developer documents a lot of time. But still I am having some unanswered questions. Can anyone give me the answers for my below questions? Thanks in advance.

My questions are

1.To integrate google wallet and test in sandbox environment should i have to sign up the Instant buy interest form?

2 . What is the need to sign up that form ? And can i sign up the form using Indian google account.?

3 . Without signing up that form can i test the application in sandbox environment.?

4 . How and where do i change the payment receiver details in sample sdk source code.?

5 . Where should i use the client Id that i created from developer console in my source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,2 and 3 : You do not need to sign up with interest form to test for sandbox. You will however need that for production access. Again for sandbox no sign up required *anywhere*. The sandbox apps just works out of the box.

4: There is no payment receiver required in the app. Instant Buy works by giving you a one time use credit card back to app. The app can then send the credit card for processing to their backend. So no payment is received from Google.

5: No where. You would just create a mapping of your app package and your app fingerprint using the client id registration in the cloud console.

Edit: Though you do not need to sign up for sandbox it is recommended to sign up early if you are going to use Instant Buy in production at getinstantbuy.withgoogle.com, this will help expedite the verification and production account setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! And when making a payment transaction using my sandbox account in the sandbox environment of the app, will i get any notification to my sandbox account.?

Comment: No you do not get any notification in sandbox account.